# How does this integral go to the next step?

Tags: integration

How did he manage to pull $1/4$ out and separate the bottom brackets in the following computation?

$$\int\frac{dy}{(y+3)(y-1)}=\frac14\left(\int\frac{dy}{y-1}-\int\frac{dy}{y+3}\right)$$

Comment: It's called partial fraction decomposition. The basic fact is that there are coefficients that let you split up the fraction like that, the hard part is finding what the coefficients are. It's covered in standard calculus books (even though technically it is purely algebra, essentially undoing the "common denominator" operation).

Comment: You can verify the result by noting that $$\int\frac{dy}{y-1}-\int\frac{dy}{y+3} = \int\left(\frac1{y-1}-\frac1{y+3}\right)dy$$ and checking that $$\frac1{y-1}-\frac1{y+3}=\frac{(y+3)-(y-1)}{(y-1)(y+3)}=\frac4{(y-1)(y+3)}\;.$$ Finding it is, as @Ian said, a bit harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to look for $a,b$ such that $\frac{a}{y-1}+\frac{b}{y+3}=\frac{1}{(y-1)(y+3)}$, and therefore, $\frac{ay+3a+by-b}{(y-1)(y+3)}=\frac{1}{(y-1)(y+3)}$, such that $(a+b)y+(3a-b)=1$, and therefore, $a+b=0 ,3a-b=1$. Let's write $b=-a$, such that $3a-(-a)=1$, and therefore $a=\frac{1}{4}$, and since $b=-a$, then $b=-\frac{1}{4}$, such that $\frac{1}{(y-1)(y+3)}=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{y-1}-\frac{1}{y+3})$

Comment: Ahh, I see! Thank you very much :)